# EternalTerminal on CentOS 7

Tags: ssh, centos7

I've been trying to get EternalTerminal working.

Whenever I `et dev` where DEV is my SSH signals I get infinite hanging.
I ensured that I actually have the server running.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you care for an answer, you can check out this issue on GitHub. https://github.com/MisterTea/EternalTerminal/issues/157